# Help understanding how even and odd cases are relevant to reflexivity

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm looking at a proof of (a,b)∈R iff 2 | a^2 +b is an equivalence relation.

When I get to the reflexive case of the proof it uses an even and odd case. How does parity relate to reflexivity?

Comment: Have you written out what reflexivity would mean?

Comment: The title is not to be used in place of the main body of the question. Please write out your question in full.

Comment: It's reflexive, because $2|c^2+c$, which can be proven by considering separate cases:  $c$ odd and $c$ even

Comment: Okay, I understand. I'm proving 2|^2+ is true with an even and odd case. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equivalence relation $R$ has to be reflexive; that means, for all $c, (c,c)\in R$.

For your particular relation, this would mean $2|c^2+c$.

It can be proven that $2|c^2+c$ by considering separate cases:

if $c$ is odd, then so is $c^2$, so $c^2+c=$ odd + odd = even;

if $c$ is even, then so is $c^2$, so $c^2+c=$ even + even = even.

Thus, for all $c$ (whether $c$ is odd or even), $2|c^2+c$, so $R$ is reflexive.

Even and odd cases are not generally directly related to reflexivity,

but the way this particular relation is defined, it helps to consider parity to show reflexivity.

Comment: you could also prove $2|c^2+c$ by noting that $c^2+c=c(c+1)$, the product of two consecutive integers; if $c$ is odd then $c+1$ is even and vice versa, so in any case $c(c+1)$ is even